# Primary Key Index on datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

If I have a table in a database with 2 columns.  1st Col is the Unique Identifier (int) and the 2nd col is someone's name (string). Lets says the data in this table looks like.

```
ID --- Name
1      John
2      Steven
3      Sven
```

When I run a query where all the names that start with 'S' it should return the result in a datagrid, but I dont want the ID to show in the datagrid but I do want the value of the ID when the cell in the datagrid is selected.

How would I accomplish this. Yes I can get the row index and col index on the grid but that wouldnt give me the true PKI of 'Steven' and 'Sven'. Should I also add 'ID' in the query and just hide it in the datagrid (not even sure if thats possible) or what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: why not to set its visibility to false?

Comment: This will helps you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-hide-columns-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set its visibility to false after binding.

```
dataGridView.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
```